# discord.py - channel.members not giving members in a channel

Tags: python, discord.py

For a command, I am trying to move every member from every channel within a specific category to another channel and the delete all the channels in that category. I have tested the code and it all works apart from the `channel.members` part. The `print(channel.members)` returns an empty list `[]` every time I run the command. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I know fetching the guild ID prevents this from working but I'm not doing that anywhere in the code.

```
#Delete all channels in Ongoing Matches
@client.command()
async def comm(ctx):
    general = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name='Vibing')
    category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name='Ongoing Matches')
    channels = category.channels
    for channel in channels:
        print(channel.members)
        for member in channel.members:
            print(member)
            await member.move_to(general)
        await channel.delete()
```

Comment: Do you want delete text channels, or voice channels?

Comment: What version of discord.py are you using? If 1.5.0, have a look at intents [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#where-d-my-members-go) .

Answer (score 1):

It's all about discord.Intents()
Head to your developer portal > your project > Bot and toggle "SERVER MEMBERS INTENT" on. Then in your project add the intents to your bot with

```
# create intents before creating bot/client instance
intents = discord.Intents().default()
intents.members = True
# create the instance
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

If you're using discord.ext.commands.Bot the process is similar, just add intents=intents to the constructor.